# BigCommerce Product Variant Images through API

Tags: api, bigcommerce

Now, Big Commerce allows you to add images to product variants through product rules; however, for the REST API, a request for all the skus (variants) of a main product does not yield a link to the images and if a request to the product rule is made, only the file location of the image is shown and not an actual link.

On the contrary, when making a request to fetch all images for a product, each of the items has an url, from which the actual image can be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the product object model. Subresources aren't expanded with their full context. We're looking at improving the object model in the near future.